# Finding a Perfect English Pangram Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The thought of pranking a coworker has lead me to thinking of ways to find perfect English Pangrams. I plan to write a program using dynamic programming techniques to try to determine possible perfect pangrams, unless someone else knows of one that already exists, or is able to provide me with a known solution.

The prank I plan to do is arrange the keys on a coworker's keyboard to be a pangram that makes sense, but in order to do so, the characters can only appear once.

As a programmer, I thought of this as an interesting problem and after doing some googling, I have not found a pangram that doesn't have repeating characters.

With the limited number of vowels of the English language, I expect it might be impossible. If it is not impossible, I'm curious is there is a sentence that can be create that will make sense.

Comment: I think it will be good to incorporate the definition of pangram in the beginning of your question, since many of us does not know what is it.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk A perfect pangram on the other hand will only contain every letter exactly once. I don't think it's possible in English, given that pretty much every occurence of q will have to have a u following it, which leaves us with 4 vowels, the vowel-ish y and 19 consonants.

Comment: It isn't impossible. Just use an anagram solver and input a-z. It'll come up with a few... but not many, and most of the words are so esoteric that it'll seem more like gibberish. Best one I saw in trying that was: "Mr. Jock TV quiz PhD bags few lynx"

Comment: Google found me http://clagnut.com/blog/2380/ without too much effort. If those look like english to you...

Comment: @neuronaut True, it is possible with acronyms and abbreviations. And Welsh words :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice problem! If I were you I would approach the problem in this way:

- find an English dictionary which has what part of the speech each word is. Discard all those words with repeating characters.
- find/create a grammar for an English sentence. It may be something like this: `S -> NP VP, NP → Pronoun | Proper-Noun | ...` [reference](http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~jkalita/work/cs589/2010/12Grammars.pdf)
- start building sentences with backtracking procedure using the grammar

Given the fact you'd like not have repeating characters in the sentence your backtracking procedure would not explore deep nodes and you can almost be sure that it would be reasonably fast.

Comment: To speed things up, I'd pre-calculate a 32 (actually only 26) bit mask for every word, with 1s for every letter the word contains. You can conveniently do this while weeding out the words that contain duplicate letters. That reduces checking letter clashes to a single bitwise `and`, and backtracking to a single `xor`.

Comment: @biziclop it's definitely a nice optimization, necessary even if the search blows up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I came across this post when trying to solve the same problem.

Essentially, I modeled the problem as a graph, and used A* search. Each node in the graph represents the number of letters not yet chosen, and each edge represents picking a word that might be in a perfect pangram.

The heuristics I used for A* are a combination of consonant-to-vowel ratio and how commonly a letter is used in a word.

My solution is open source in JavaScript, and has a more detailed explanation:

https://github.com/teb311/perfect-pangram-finder

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I edited my answer to be more in line w/ stack exchange best practices. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{

    char str[1000];
    int a[26]={0},count=0,i,n;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&str[i]);
        if(str[i]=='\n')
        break;
        else if(str[i]<=90&&str[i]>=65)
        {

            n=str[i]-'A';
            if(a[n]!=1)
            {
                a[n]++;
                count++;
            }
        }
        else if(str[i]<=122&&str[i]>=97)
        {

            n=str[i]-'a';
            if(a[n]!=1)
            {
                a[n]++;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==26)
        {
            printf("pangram");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("not pangram");
}
```

Comment: please add a description as to how this resolves the askers question